# Joomla PHP Form on IIS Server with Windows - errors

Tags: php, windows, iis, joomla

I'm having a problem with my Joomla contact form. At the moment I'm using a module called Rapid Contact, which is not really important, it works on other websites I have but I'm having trouble with this website.

I'm having trouble because my company is running an IIS Windows server, with PHP installed on there and the Joomla site also stored there. The site itself runs find, but when I try to mail someone using this form, it says 'could not instantiate mail function', when I use 'PHP Mail Function (in Global Configuration), an error when I change it to 'Sendmail' in the settings, and an error when I change it to 'SMTP'.

My question is, what settings can i use to get around this problem? Does IIS conflict with PHP? I'm not using FTP, and despite my suggestion, they are adamant it can work without getting web space to use FTP.

Perhaps there is someway I can modify the php.ini file to get around this?

Hope someone can help,

Kind Regards,

Snakespan

Comment: Edited the tags to include rapid-contact

Answer (score 1):

I'm Christopher Mavros, the author of Rapid Contact.
You may want to try to set the parameter "Disable HTTPS" to true, and try again.

If that doesn't work, then you can come to [my website](http://mavrosxristoforos.com/contact) and contact me directly to visit your url and check the error myself.

For anyone reading this post: You can also post any mavrosxristoforos.com extension related questions on the [forum](http://mavrosxristoforos.com/support/forum) section.

Thanks for using Rapid Contact.

Comment: thx for taking the time to answer the question and welcome to SO. I've edited your post to include the links, but be careful with mentioning your website too often. People tend to be sensitive to self promotion and might flag it as spam if it happens too often. Also bluntly asking to post on the forum is not done. SO is a platform where programmers help eachother out, so these questions will pop up here as well. I changed it to a possibility, which seems more appropriate for this site. Don't take this personal, it's just to avoid you getting in trouble. Cheers

Comment: I included a tag rapid-contact, so you can follow the tag and find questions about it easily. In the tag description, I link to your site. Hope that helps.